# If $a,b,c$ are positive reals satisfying $a+b+c \geq abc$, prove that: $a^2+b^2+c^2 \geq \sqrt 3abc$

Tags: inequality

If $a,b,c$ are positive reals satisfying $a+b+c \geq abc$, prove that: $a^2+b^2+c^2 \geq \sqrt 3abc$

I've been trying to solve the above question since a long time but I'm not able to. I'm not able to understand how to use this condition (I've generally dealt with inequalities having conditions as a sum = constant). Would someone please help me to solve this question?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are $a,b,c$ positive?

Comment: Yes. I mentioned that $a,b,c$ are positive reals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $$a^2+b^2+c^2\geq\sqrt{3abc(a+b+c)}\geq\sqrt3abc.$$

Comment: Oh! Missed that! Thank you Michael.

Comment: @Shashwat1337 You are welcome!

Comment: Why does the first inequality hold...?